# Why is motion tweening changing the size/proportion of my movieclip?

Tags: flash, resize, movieclip

I am having a really odd problem with Flash CS4. I have a MovieClip with the dimensions 652x400. When I create a motion tween for the layer containing the clip, and move the playhead to the last frame of the tween, I check the dimensions of the same MovieClip, and it's been changed to 660x408, regardless of the fact that I haven't even put in a keyframe at the end of the tween. What's weirder still is that the object looks the exact same size at the end of the tween as it does at the beginning, despite the fact that it's gained 8 pixels on each side. Flash seems to be arbitrarily resizing my MovieClips. Has anyone had this problem before and can anyone shed some light?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay so I've done some experimentation, and have figured out what's causing the discrepancy in the dimensions. The MovieClip has a blur filter on it, from the first tween frame to the last. What's odd is that even if this filter is set to 0px x 0px blur throughout the tween, the last frame is still 660x408. Essentially it still changes the dimensions whether or not you choose to actually use the blur, the fact that it's even on the MovieClip is enough to change it. Anyone with any clue as to what's going on?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any subclips inside the MovieClip? Are you entirely sure it's a MovieClip and not a Graphic? Animating graphics on the timeline can have strange effects.

Comment: it is a MovieClip containing several subclips. I guess that might be enough to freak flash out, but I don't know.